# Finding the angle.

Tags: trigonometry, solid-angle

first question here.

I ran into a problem where my math skills are just not enough, probably it's simple, but I don't know how to approach it.

I'll show you this graphic so you can understand what I need to find:

[image: finding beta]

The green line represents the movement of an unit in a videogame I'm developing, the idea is that the unit can accelerate until it reaches the proper angle, then it advances in a straight line and then "parks the car".

Programatically speaking, I need to know the value of the ß angle before I even start moving the unit, then it's just a mirror, no problem from there.

Do you guys have an idea of how to find such angle based on what I've showed you?.

Comment: The green one is a curve up until the second horizontal, no? What sort of curve is it?

Comment: Yeah the green represents the entire movement, so it begins as a curve, then is a line and then a curve again. There are no 2 lines, the black ones are just a visual aid I used to show the angle. 

I don't know what kind of curve it is, I only know that the rotation of the unit is linear and the x, and y are accelerating, that is, every frame there is a fixed quantity added.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking what kind of curve do you have there. If it is, say, a Bézier curve, then there should be derivative information involved, which you can use to compute the angle you want.

Comment: I honestly don't know what kind of curve the unit is drawing when it moves, I only know that I increment the rotation linearly (it doesn't accelerate over time) and I increment the X and Y by a fixed amount every frame, something like speed = speed + 1. That is what generate the curve. If needed I can change the way it accelerates, and even change the rotation increment formula. But still, I wouldn't know what to do with them :p

Comment: In that case: could you indicate the relevant potion of your code for generating this curve?

Comment: Sure, every frame, this is what I do with the unit's rotation and movement:

unit.rotation ++;

obj.x += Math.cos(unit.rotation) * speed;
obj.y += Math.sin(unit.rotation) * speed;

speed ++;

Comment: What are the initial values of `unit.rotation` and `speed`? You are incrementing them, so it looks to me that you are generating what is called the [spiral of Archimedes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral), but we ought to be certain...

Comment: ... and after a while you continue with constant movement (i.e. no rotation++ and no speed ++) and then in the end you decelerate symmetrically (with speed-- and rotation--)?

Comment: @J.M rotation initial value will vary, in this case, it's -90 degrees. speed is always 0.

Hagen yes, exactly, its  symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Stop rotating when $\frac{midpoint.x-obj.x}{midpoint.y-obj.y}\approx\tan( unit.rotation)$

Comment: I don't think that would work, because the first division in the formula represents the angle between the starting and final position, not the modified angle I need.